# Assign command line to program

Tags: linux, command-line

On my Linux, I have installed three versions of the same program.

So I have QWERTY4.0, QWERTY4.1 and QWERTY4.2.

I use all of them alternatively but the default linux command line "qwerty" sends me to QWERTY4.0 version.

How can I change which version should this command go to? And more generally, how can one assign a command to open a certain program, if the command doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1):

You can start a specific version of the program by prefixing the exact path to the binary, e.g. `/path/to/qwerty4.0/qwerty`, `/path/to/qwerty4.1/qwerty`, etc.

You can create an alias and add this to your shell configuration (`.bashrc` if your shell is bash):

```
alias qwerty40=/path/to/qwerty4.0/qwerty
alias qwerty41=/path/to/qwerty4.1/qwerty
alias qwerty41=/path/to/qwerty4.2/qwerty
```

Answer (score 1):

Some quick hints:

```
which qwerty
file $(which qwerty)
```

*which* outputs the absolute path of the executable/symlink to the executable. The second command just gets the ouput (path) from the *which* command so I don't have to type it out. You can also use the *type* command (instead of *which*) to figure out the absolute path.
*file* will tell you if it is a symlink or a script or maybe even an executable.

The file might be a simple symlink pointing to qwerty4.0. If so there is a possibility it is controlled through the *alternatives* (or *update-alternatives*) system. You can figure this out by looking at the output from `update-alternatives --get-selections`. If it is you can change the default with something like `update-alternatives --config qwerty`.
It it is not controlled by the *alternatives* system (but is a symlink) you can update the symlink like so:

```
ln -s -f /path/to/qwerty4.2/qwerty /usr/local/bin/qwerty
```

...assuming `which qwerty` gave */usr/local/bin/qwerty*.

It might also be a launcher, usually a shell/bash script. If so you can either just try and change (edit) it to point launch the correct version. You could also go look in the respective application directory looking for an updated version of this launcher and then copy it in-place.

If it is a straight executable you could possibly just copy in a new one, but if so I would rather recommend replacing it with an appropriate symlink.

Aliases have already been mentioned. Aliases work well, but if you need a system-wide solution symlinks are usually a faster way. Also, depending on how system-wide shell aliases are set up they might not work across different shells etc. Local (bash) aliases can be kept in *.bashrc* or possibly *.bash_aliases*. If you want system-wide aliases */etc/profile.d/* may be a good place to put them (should work for most/all shells).